Malcolm in the Middle episode where Hal shouts in a box out of despair
Scene:
Hal and Lois are both in the bathroom and discuss (or discover) another haywire situation that their children triggered. Hal calmly asks for the box (which has a dedicated name I can't remember), places it shut over its head, and screams, losing all manner of composure.
Which episode is that? What is the name of the box?
(Bonus points for a youtube excerpt, animated gif, or something to that effect)

I'm not sure you're able to give bonus points lol!

The episode is Hal's Dentist from 2006 (Season 7, Episode 17).

Hal feels betrayed when his friend Trey charges $2,000 to fix Hal's teeth; Malcolm and Dewey find a new mattress; and Reese teaches Lois how to ride a bike.

He's naturally frustrated by the dentist situation.

Lois: Well, you are going to have to find some way to deal with this.
Hal: I know and I have. I'm not an idiot, Lois. Now, please, will you
  hand me my scream box?

Here's the clip:




Here's your bonus point!: +1 :-D
